# Cakephp2.6でelementのctpファイルでSmartyが動作しない

Tags: cakephp, smarty

**質問内容**
Cakephp2.6 で Smarty を使用しているのですが、element にctpファイルを作成して view から呼び出そうとすると、呼び出し先でSmarty が動かすとき、そのまま Smarty のタグが表示されてしまいます。

View フォルダに入っている ctp はきちんと Smarty が動作いたします。
(element フォルダでは PHP のデフォルトテンプレートエンジンがなぜか動作しました。)

良い解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

---

**現状:**

- Smarty は呼び込めて動作しています。Cake の `Helper` 関数も動作します。
- `{$View->element('hoge') nofilter}` で呼び出すと、たとえばこのような `{foreach hoge}` のタグがそのまま排出されてしまいます。View フォルダのファイルはきちんと表示されます。
- element の ctp ファイルは Smarty は動作しませんがなぜかデフォルトの `<?php ?>` のテンプレートエンジンは動作しました。(View ファイルでは `<?php ?>` のタグは動作しません。)
- Smarty はオートエスケープにしています。
- 拡張子は ctp です。

---

以上、お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ヒント等でもうれしいです。
StackOverflow初めてなので、情報がわかりにくい等ありましたら、追記いたします！

Comment: 今の現状の回避方法はViewはSmartyで記述し、Elementの中のctpファイルでは<?php ?>を使用して、回避していますが、気持ち悪いのと、ソースコードの一貫性が無いので、出来る限りSmartyで記述したいです。

Comment: CakePHPでSmartyを利用する時のプラグイン？はいくつかあるようですが、どちらを使われているのでしょうか。

Comment: 実はプロジェクトを引き継ぎましたが、どのSmartyプラグインを利用しているのかはわかりません。ViewフォルダにSmartyView.phpを入れるタイプのプラグイン？だと思います。(今手元にソースが無く確認できなくて申し訳ないです。)
引き継いでからSmartyView.phpにオートエスケープが有効になるよう修正しましたが、何か関係あるのでしょうか。
elementフォルダには引き継ぎ当初には空のhogehoge.ctp(ファイル名仮)が放置されていました。
Smartyの使用方法は{$this->Html->link()}ではなく{$View->Html->link()}のような記述になっていました。

（担当者に聞くのが一番かと思われるかもしれませんが、察していただければうれしいです。）

Comment: なかなか問題を特定しづらいのですが、使われている SmartyView.php のコードは、例えば http://www18.atwiki.jp/javascripter/pages/26.html これと似ているでしょうか？ (特に _render の中身)

Comment: かなり似ています。
ただ_renderの中身だけはほとんど気にかけていなかったのでもしかしたら違う部分がありそうです。(月曜日に出社するので確認します。)

色々助言ありがとうございます。月曜日にSmartyViewをもう一度見なおしてみます!

Comment: マルチポスト　http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1426179935